# how to get data from virtuemart categories tables?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5, virtuemart

hi i need to make a drop down list field in a form (RSForm **joomla 2.5**), that will drew its values from virtuemart categories names. 
i have this block of code that i need to customize to my needs but since i dont know php all my improvisations ended up in fatal error and need to reinstall the form again:(

the name of my table in mysql is `xxx_virtuemart_categories_he_il`

the names of the categories are listed here `category_names`

their id's are here `virtuemart_category_id`

this is the block of code how do i change it?

```
//<code>
// Prepare the empty array
$items = array();
// Prepare the database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Run the SQL query and store it in $results
$db->setQuery("SELECT your_value, your_label FROM #__your_table");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
// Now, we need to convert the results into a readable RSForm! Pro format.
// The Items field will accept values in this format:
// value-to-be-stored|value-to-be-shown
 foreach ($results as $result) {
 $value = $result->your_value;
 $label = $result->your_label;
 $items[] = $value.'|'.$label;
  }

// Multiple values are separated by new lines, so we need to do this now
$items = implode("\n", $items);

// Now we need to return the value to the field
 return $items;
 //</code>
```

Comment: `$db->setQuery("SELECT your_value, your_label FROM #__your_table");`, this is where you should specify the columns you want to select and the table name. It's SQL, so go look that up if you need any help with it. I've not used joomla 2.5, so I don't know how to get the errors etc if there is any, but I'd look into that if I were you to make sure the SQL isn't giving you any issues. In the foreach loop you seem to be supposed to use the selected columns from the SQL query, but each result seem to be an object, so they are properties of the object rather than indexes in an array.

Comment: thank you so from what i understand -SQL is not the same as mySQL and this code will not work ? and this is how this line of code should look?                                                                 $db->setQuery("SELECT category_names, virtuemart_category_id FROM xxx_virtuemart_categories_he_il");

Comment: MySQL uses "normal" SQL syntax. That does look correct. You can at the documentation/API for the JDatabase object [here](http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JDatabase). Looking at that you should try the following `echo $db->getErrorMsg();` after `$results = $db->loadObjectList();` to see the SQL error.

Comment: the error is:                                                   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 SQL=SELECT category_names, virtuemart_category_id FROM #_virtuemart_categories_he_il

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
$db->query();
```

before:

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: sorry nothing change :(

Comment: do i need to change it to this format?                                 // Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));                                           
$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'custom.%\''));
$query->order('ordering ASC');

Comment: Could you try `echo $db->getLog();` before and after `$db->setQuery();`. Also give us the exact message from that and from doing this after setQuery(): `echo $db->getQuery();`;

Answer (score 0):

The fast and simple solution to connect to a bd in virtuemart is:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...");
$db->query();
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

echo var_dump($results);
```